# CI pipeline with Anti Virus Scan

Tags: docker, devops, bitbucket-pipelines, antivirus

We have a CI pipeline on bitbucket that produces installer files of our product.

We would like to automatically scan these files for viruses.

**Requirements:**

- a) Runs inside a docker.
  Either as an whole image, an executable or an web service.
- b) License is free or paid.
  But should work in a cloud environment, so no license with hardware pinning/dongles etc.
- c) Scan quality is very good
- d) Should handle large Files (~1.5 Gb)

Possible candidates so far:

- [clamav](https://www.clamav.net/)
  *Note: unsure about its scan quality(c)*
- VirusTotal  *Note: unsure about its scan quality(c)*
- binaryalert.io *Note: Needs AWS Stack(a),  unsure about its scan quality(c)*
- docs.docker.com/engine/scan *Note: Must be a docker file, unsure about its scan quality(c)*
- https://virusscan.jotti.org *Note: Uses multiple SCAN engines(c), but is is limited to 250 MB files (d)*
- <s>[Sophos Anti-Virus for Linux Free Edition](https://community.sophos.com/free-tools/b/blog/posts/retirement-of-sophos-anti-virus-for-linux-free-edition)</s> End of life 1.1.2022

The scan quality is a big issue for our product. To circumvent it  we should use multiple scan engines.

Comment: What is the question ?

You are asking for a which tool/product to use in your pipeline ?

Comment: Could this be of interest ? https://binaryalert.io/index.html, ClamAv has a unofficial rest api https://github.com/solita/clamav-rest, Docker also offer some kind of scanner https://docs.docker.com/engine/scan/

Comment: Have you already found a provider? We are thinking about the same idea and stumbled over VirusTotal, but we are still not sure if an external scanner is required or Windows Defender is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the core question here, my best guess is leveraging something like [octopus deploy](https://octopus.com/features). You can install it via a container, and building the pipeline you can leverage the AV choice that fits our requirements.

I've seen octopus deploy work extremely well in environments that have mandated AV scanning, it's worth taking a look.

Comment: I can image octopus to help rollout the virus scan to different machines. However I can not easily find an example under https://library.octopus.com/listing.
Do you have examples for your mentioned mandated AV scanning steps?

Comment: Alas, all the examples Ive seen are proprietary at .NET companies. If your truly interested I’d reach out to octopus and say what you're looking to do, they'll bring a SA with the best practices to you in no time.